# Spring not inject ServletContext

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.0.7 and for some reason in our JBOSS web app we can't get the `ServletContext` into our bean:

```
@Component("assembler")
public class DefaultAssemblerStrategy implements AssemblerStrategy//, ServletContextAware
{

   @Autowired//(required=false)
   private ServletContext servletCtxt;

   public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext)
   {
      System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~setServletContext");
      servletCtxt = servletContext;
   }
```

Note this is on the actual web server not during a JUnit test case run.

If I try the Autowired I get this error:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'assembler': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.servlet.ServletContext com.ibm.retail.xc.maestro.web.theme.impl.DefaultAssemblerStrategy.servletCtxt; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.servlet.ServletContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1073)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
```

And if I implement the `ServletContextAware` it is just null...

Comment: How and where have you configured the application context?

Comment: We have a custom dispatcherservlet, and that is in the web.xml as normal.  I have been able to autowire ApplicationContext, but not ServletConfig.

Comment: Well, the error makes sense to me unless you a have a `ServletContext` defined as a bean in your Spring configuration. Now, the `ServletContextAware` should work but it depends on a proper configuration.

Comment: @arinte: `ServletConfig`?  Your question says `ServletContext`. Which is it?

Comment: So defining the ServletContext as a bean is the common thing to do?  I thought it was something that was automatic with Spring?

Comment: @skaffman mean ServletContext sorry.

Comment: Just to check: Do you have a copy of `servlet-api.jar` in your webapp's `lib` directory, or something with a similar name?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not using `ContextLoaderListener`. `ServletContextAware` relies on a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` that is set up by `AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext` inside `refresh()`. The context relies on `ContextLoader` to inject the `ServletContext` into it. Therefore you can resolve this issue by using `ContextLoaderListener` in your application, or (probably more simply) calling `AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext#setServletContext()` before the context is refreshed.

Defining a `ServletContext` bean might also work, but conceptually the servlet context is "outside" the Spring context--really it's the servlet context that is managing the Spring context, not vice versa. Happily this approach is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I don't think this is true.  The `ServletContext` is available to Spring's infrastructure whether the `ContextLoaderListener` is enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

madth3 has indicated a possible reason: namely that a bean is defined with the name applicationContext. This makes sense e.g. for testing with a MockApplicationContext, but not in the application itself.